# Node containing text?

Tags: interface, node-editor

Is it possible to add a node to the middle of, say, a material, that just contains plaintext information for people viewing the node tree?

I know that it's possible to add a tooltip to frames, which are nice for organizing, but screen real estate for what I'm working on requires that the text be wrapped into the node itself; basically so that I can reference it without having to pop over to another viewer or such, sort of the equivalent of adding comments in a programming language.

Comment: You can use a frame to achieve this. Frames are generally used to explain and group nodes/node layouts.

Comment: You could also try the *Grease pencil* (Ctrl+LMB on the node editor). It takes some skill with a mouse (Though I imagine this might actually work nicely with a tablet)

Answer (score 8):

[As of 2.74](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/UI#Node_Editor) you can display a text datablock in a frame node:

[image]

It's still quite limited, but at least it's somewhat possible now.

Answer (score 7):

No such composite node exists *(I am assuming you want it for that pane, but most of these are in Material and Texture too)*. Here are all the [different types](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/index.html#node-types) of composite nodes in Blender.

> ### Types of Composite Nodes
>
> This section is organized by type of nodes, which are grouped based on
> similar functions:
>
> - Input - Adds something to the node map, such as an image or a value.
> - Output - Displays the result in progress as a small image.
> - Color - Manipulates the colors of an image.
> - Vector - Manipulate the intensities and reflections of an image
> - Filters - Process the image to enhance it, working on adjacent pixels.
> - Converters - Separate the image into its component video, or convert formats.
> - Mattes - Generating mattes to mask off areas of an image.
> - Distortion - Changing the shape of the image.
> - Groups - User-defined groups of nodes.

At most you can change the name of the label.

Comment: The no node exists thing seems to be the correct answer, unfortunately.