# Is there an addon for todo management?

Tags: workflow, add-on

Like something that hooks into the text editor, or maybe the node editor?

I'd like an addon that allows me to keep track of things I'd like to do (or have done) on a model.

Comment: Okay, this is one of my more reluctant calls, but I'm thinking that this is off topic? I'm saying this because it's more about something that would be done with an external program rather than Blender, and it's not really about CG. Again, I'm not 100% sure about this, but I though I'd put out my opinion anyway.

Comment: @TARDISMaker IMO it's fine. Even if the answer is "no, there is no addon. Use XYZ program instead", the *question* is asking if there is an existing way to do this in blender.

Comment: The text editor works fine for that, you can setup a small text editor at the bottom of the properties or to one side of the timeline and add/remove things as you go. For more features use an external app.

Comment: @gandalf3 is correct. I'm asking if this is possible in Blender because I'm actually tracking my progress on a weapon model that is rather complicated, and do not want to store the info about what ideas I plan to implement in another program. I've been using the text editor so far but it has been feeling a little limited as it isn't designed for this purpose (if you use todo lists often you'll know what I mean). The suggestion in the accepted answer looks like it should do almost exactly what I mean.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z0OOs8IG5OU/Vq5wlg7eAVI/AAAAAAAAtgg/G5JOK_v1GJ0/w525-h382-p-rw/HybridRifle11.png

A screenshot for the curious among us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Generic Note](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Generic_Note) Add-on which allows to create some kind of **sticky note** in the *Compositor*. In this case I'd suggest re-using a text file from the *Text Editor*:

[image]

[image]

In addition there is a nice [Comment Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7833/3710) Add-on by @CoDEmanX, which allows **creating a list**:

[image]

---

Since Blender 2.74, you can use the built-in [Frame Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/layout/frame.html#text-display) to display text blocks in the *Node Editor*:

[image]

Further information: [Is there a way to make comments in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32842/3710)