# Is there a way to add a note/comment to an individual node?

Tags: node-editor

For example: In a normal map node "Adjusting the strength of this node will effect "X" quality of the material"?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/is-there-a-way-to-make-comments-in-the-node-editor

Comment: you can use grease or script for comments about nodes.

Comment: @Dontwalk I'd suggest *Generic Node Add-on* which looks nicer than the built-in *Frame Node*: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45933/is-there-an-addon-for-todo-management/45947#45947